# What is the current cost-per-pound to send something into LEO?

Tags: launch, commercial, cost

As a student of economics and finance I would love to learn more about the cost structures of sending a payload into orbit.

More specifically -

- What is the cost-per-pound to send something into LEO for the handful of operating private and public space programs?
- How has the cost-per-pound to orbit changed over the years?

**UPDATE**:
Has anyone come across newer costs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The cost depends on the rocket, and on the percent capacity of said rocket, but here's a few numbers for you, cost in U.S. dollars/kg to LEO ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_launch_systems)*). It should be noted that not all rocket prices are publicly available, in fact, most aren't.

- Falcon Heavy: \$2200
- Falcon 9 v 1.1- \$4,109
- DNEPR- \$3,784
- Ariane 5- \$10,476
- Delta IV- \$13,072
- Atlas V- \$13,182

---

* Cost per kg to LEO column has since been removed from linked to Wikipedia page. Here is a link to the [latest archived version that still includes that column](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comparison_of_orbital_launch_systems&oldid=590182048).

Comment: Is it merely a matter of company policy that price to LEO is often not public? Any idea?

Comment: I don't believe these Falcon 9 numbers have ever been substantiated in the form of a contract.

Comment: One problem with this is there are a lot of variables in to this calculation, even "stock" rockets are custom designed for each mission. And not giving the price publicly allows them to play favorites.

Comment: @AlanSE SpaceX is pretty much the only company that actually quotes a price publically.  Beyond NASA they have dozens of launches booked.  So some companies have clearly bought launches.  CSA and Cassiope is a known discount case.  But SES and Thiacom are next, surely they have signed a contract for those launches?

Comment: I note the absence of a number for the Shuttle!  Good choice, since of course the Shuttle numbers range from nonsensical (\$500 mil/launch) to more reasonable (\$1.5 billion) to the far extremes.  Depends what you count.  Same issue for Saturn V, and pretty much all NASA launchers.

Comment: @geoffc: It's much easier to compare commercial launches. Government launches are very difficult to price...

Comment: @geoffc: I know at least Orbcomm has a contract, ported at a discount. http://spaceflightnow.com/news/n1301/01orbcomm/ . The article indicates that it is due to a prior contract to launch their satellites on a Falcon 1, which was discontinued.

Comment: Also, [SES](http://spaceflightnow.com/news/n1209/17spacexses/) has one with no price listed, and [Thaicomm](http://spaceflightnow.com/news/n1211/17f9customers/#.UjdoBX9jHSg) has one, no price listed. At the least, the Falcon 9 prices are no higher than is listed on their website, thus I think the price is reasonable to be included.

Comment: "Cost" and "price" are two different things.  The numbers provided in this answer mix the two.

Comment: Also, it is probably reasonable to normalize these costs for system risk.  A low price per pound sounds great until you realize it will take three launches to get to orbit...

Comment: If you think about all the contributors to launch cost and all the variables associated with a spacecraft launch, it's hard to imagine that a cost per kg could in most cases be anything better than a rough statistic. That SpaceX can actually quote a price (presumably for marketing purposes) seems to say a lot about both containing costs and controlling all the variables.

Comment: Falcon Heavy: $2200/kg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_Heavy#Pricing_and_development_funding

Comment: No amount of money gets you a Falcon Heavy launch at present.

Comment: You can buy one, it just won't laugh for a while.

Comment: Interesting how cost will change after success of spacex falcon 9 full thrust?

Comment: Full thrust? Not much. The reusable first stage will reduce the cost by about 30%, however. I suspect more for the Falcon Heavy.

Comment: According to <http://time.com/money/5135565/elon-musk-falcon-heavy-rocket-launch-cost/> the Falcon Heavy cost about \$90M per launch and carries a (non-fuel) payload of about 140,000 lbs. On my calculator that's about \$642.86/lb.

Comment: @geowar The number there is wrong. The cost is $90 million if the boosters are all preserved. The cost goes up if at the max capacity.