# Would it be possible to Boost ISS to L1 or Lunar Orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, orbital-maneuver, lagrangian-points, lunar-orbit

NASA and Russia plan to retire the ISS before 2030, and to launch a new lunar outpost to lunar orbit. This output could then be a gateway to future mission to Mars or the outer solar system.

My question is this: NASA has already spent hundreds of billions of dollars to build the ISS; it seems an awful shame to let that burn up in the atmosphere. I know that they regularly boost the altitude of the station.

1. Would be *at least possible* to boost the station to lunar orbit or at least to an Earth-Moon Lagrange point where minimal station-keeping could used to maintain orbit?
2. How much fuel would be required to get to either of those orbits? What would be involved in transporting that much fuel to the ISS?
3. How much fuel per year delivered to the ISS's new orbit would be required to keep it in either of these orbits, rather than it eventually crashing into the Moon or wandering away chaotically? Could solar-electric help here?

   - [Will the ISS have electric propulsion to maintain altitude? Is there enough power for it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19816/12102)
   - [Will the Neumann drive start testing aboard the ISS some time in 2018?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27185/12102)
   - [Which way will the Neumann drive (on the ISS) point, what will be its maximum possible thrust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27201/12102)

Comment: These are not duplicates, but there may be some helpful information in them: 1. [How feasible would it be to move the ISS to the surface of the Moon to recycle its components in future?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33813/12102) 2. [What would be needed for ISS to function in lunar orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29543/12102) 3. [How much energy would it require to get the ISS to the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23478/12102) 4. [Would it make sense to salvage parts of the ISS as it is decommissioned?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16807/12102)

Comment: I'm not sure, but is L1 stable? I thought L1 halo orbits still required stationkeeping.

Comment: @Dragongeek I've just edited the question. I have a hunch that stationkeeping at a Earth-Moon Lagrange point could require less fuel per year than in LEO at 400 km if managed carefully, but I don't know. Of course moving all of this fuel to the ISS is probably a big challenge.

Comment: @user33047 I've made some edits to your question to help it to be unique because there have been several related questions asked in the past. Feel free to roll-back or edit further. *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: @uhoh I mean the answers are all kind of duplicates, "It can't/won't happen".

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn "duplicate" has a very specific meaning in Stack Exchange. It's better to use a different phrase than "kind of duplicate" to avoid confusing new users.

Comment: Possible?  Yes.  Practical?  No.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before getting to the technical feasibility of *moving* the ISS, I feel obligated to point out that operating it at L1 or lunar orbit is impractical for a few reasons:

- The ISS is designed for the radiation environment of low Earth orbit. Outside of low Earth orbit, without the protection of the Van Allen radiation belt, crew aboard the station will receive much more radiation exposure.
- The ISS depends on regular supply missions from Earth. To supply it at L1 or lunar orbit would require much larger launchers, or more frequent launches of very small payloads.
- Crew transport to and from the station, likewise, would have to be done on bigger rockets. The [Soyuz launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz-2) can't send a crew to L1 or the moon; the [Soyuz spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_MS) can't get home from there.

The ISS is already cripplingly expensive to operate in LEO; outside of Earth orbit the costs would increase by about an order of magnitude.

> Would it be at least possible to boost the station to lunar orbit or at least to an Earth-Moon Lagrange point where minimal station-keeping could used to maintain orbit? How much fuel would be required to get to either of those orbits? What would be involved in transporting that much fuel to the ISS?

The delta-V requirements from LEO to either the Earth-Moon L1 point or the "Lunar Gateway" orbit are pretty similar -- [3.77 km/s for EML1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget#Earth%E2%80%93Moon_space%E2%80%94high_thrust), or [3.63 km/s for Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget#Earth_Lunar_Gateway%E2%80%94high_thrust). For EML1, using [the rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) ...

$$\Delta v = v_\text{e} \ln \frac{m_0}{m_f} = I_\text{sp} g_0 \ln \frac{m_0}{m_f}$$

...with a specific impulse of 302 seconds (corresponding to the Zvezda thrusters of the ISS, but typical of any hypergolic bipropellant thruster), we get an initial to final mass ratio of 3.57 -- that is, you need about 1030 tons of fuel to push the 400 ton ISS to that destination.

To low lunar orbit is 4.04 km/s, which would require a 3.91 mass ratio, you need 1165 tons of fuel per 400 tons of station.

This would obviously require a substantial addition of tankage modules to the ISS -- a huge project in itself, and pushing the dry mass up, requiring still more fuel. Assuming you're launching the tankage and propellant on something like a [Proton rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton-M) with around 20 ton payload capacity, I'd say four launches to add the tanks, then *60 more launches* to load the propellant. A larger-payload launcher like Falcon Heavy could possibly bring this down to around 25 launches.

With an ion thruster or similar electric propulsion, the fuel requirements come way down. Low-thrust translunar flight requires substantially more delta-v (the [Oberth effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect) is maximized by short, high-thrust burns, which electric thrusters can't achieve) -- around [7km/s to EML1 or 8 km/s to LLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget#Earth%E2%80%93Moon_space%E2%80%94low_thrust). With a specific impulse of ~4000 seconds (achieved by the [NEXT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXT_(ion_thruster)) thruster), only around 100 tons of fuel and tankage would be required. This could possibly be done with a medium-lift mission for the tankage and maybe 5 Protons or 2 Falcon Heavies for the propellant.

Comment: So, basically, the answer is "no", and likely, "they've thought of that".

Comment: Well, it's not impossible in the sense of "can't physically be done". It's impossible in the sense of "it's a bad idea and no one can afford to do it."